# Possible to use android wear watchfaces as widget on a normal android smartphone?

Tags: widget, wear-os, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is it possible to use a watchface as regular widget on an android smartphone?

I found some interesting watchfaces where no similar widgets are availaible and asked myself if it couldn't be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they do not work as widgets on your phone.